Ошибка в работе программы на языке С
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXVAL 100
double stack[MAXVAL];
int sp = 0;

void push(double f){
    if (sp < MAXVAL) stack[sp++] = f;
    else printf("Error: stack is full, no memory for %g\n", f);
}

double pop(void){
    if (sp > 0) return stack[--sp];
    else {
        printf("Error: no stack\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *c;
    double op2;
    int flag = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        c = argv[i];
        if (*c == '+'){
            push(pop() + pop());
        }
        else if (*c == '*'){
            push(pop() * pop());
        }
        else if (*c == '-'){
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
        }
        else if (*c == '/'){
            op2 = pop();
            if (op2 != 0.0) push(pop() / op2);
            else{
                printf("Division by zero\n"); 
            }
        }
        else if (isdigit((unsigned char)*c)) push(atof(c));
    }
    if (sp > 0 && flag) printf("%.8f\n", pop()); // Печатаем результат
    else printf("Error: no result on the stack\n");

    return 0;
}

Доброго времени суток! Не могу понять, почему знак * обрабатывается некорректно. Буду благодарен за помощь!

А как он должен обрабатываться? Вы забыли рассказать что работает неправильно и как должно работать правильно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Задание звучит таким образом: Напишите программу expr, интерпретирующую обратную польскую запись выражения,
задаваемого командной строкой, в которой каждый оператор и операнд представлены отдельным аргументом.

Какая ОС? Какой терминал? Как воспроизвести ошибку?

Ответ здесь

@StanislavVolodarskiy Windows 10, Powershell. При вводе 5 10 * выводится 10

Наверное вы вызываете в терминале из bash (или другого shell) и он вместо * подставляет список файлов в текущем каталоге.
Попробуйте ./a.out 2 3 \*

К сожалению не помогает, выводит число, которое было последнее в стеке. В вашем случае вывело 3

@Treeesk, значит делаете что-то не так. Я копипастнул и скомпилировал ваш код в ~/avp/hashcode$ uname -a Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-150-generic ...   и запустил  ~/avp/hashcode$ gcc t-calc.c && ./a.out 2 3 \* 6.00000000 avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ (видите 6.00000000 ?) (к сожалению не могу в комментарии отформатировать с нормальным переходом по строкам)

@avp, скажем, в Windows это будет работать по другому. Я бы сперва добился понятного вопроса, а уж потом тратил время.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, ну, с виндой я совсем не дружу ...

@avp Видимо это связано с работой на Windows

@Treeesk, возможно, Вы не заметили мой комментарий к вопросу. Ответ дан здесь. Я проверил на winlibs-mingw под Win10. Если просто скомпилить, то * будет обрабатываться не так, как хочется; а если объявить глобальную переменную int _CRT_glob = 0;, то поведение будет соответствовать ожидаемому.

@OldSkull, ну, в винде все не как у людей...

@avp, там написано "the default behaviour differs between compilers." и приведено два примера различного поведения. С линуксом я давно не сталкивался, но не вижу причин, по которым и в этих  ОС не может быть подобного бардака.

@OldSkull, коренное отличие в том, что в винде globbing (и следовательно модификация argv[]) делается внутри запускаемой программы, а в *nix-ах (в т.ч. в linux) этим занимается исключительно запускающая программа (обычно shell)
